# Should I use Rail's find methods vs using Thinking Sphinx or some other search framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I would like to add a search/browse feature to my website.

Users will be able to search for people by email address or first and last name. They'll also be able to browse through the site's users with the option of using the following search filters:

```
age range
country 
location (city)
gender
```

Should this be done without the use of something like Thinking Sphinx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used sphinx in my real projects.
I would recommend you to use thinking sphinx gem with Sphinx Search for following reasons:

**1: Performence**
        All your searchable data will become search index file. Therefore while user 
        perform their search, there is no SQL query to the database.

**2: It is easier to do complex search**. If you have a look [thinking sphinx wiki](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html)
        you will see how many different kind of search you can do with it. Plus the 
        Geo-location Search. It is very hard or a lot more work needed if you do it by 
        using Rails `where` methods or SQL query.

By the way, use [delta index](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html) and scheduled rake tasks to keep your search index up to date.

I normally rebuild my search index every early morning.

Comment: It's worth noting that there still will be a SQL query - to translate Sphinx results into ActiveRecord objects - but this is done by the primary key, so it's almost certainly still a net win.

Comment: Thanks as I was wondering how it was the search would be done. Sphinx is installed and I'm ready to go. From the screencast I'm watching it looks fairly straight forward.

Comment: If I would have known setting search filters wasn't straight forward or even doable I wouldn't have bothered myself with this thinking sphinx.